# No more scroll wheel scrolling along the sidebar in 13.04?

Tags: unity, mouse, mouse-scroll

Just upgraded to 13, and one thing that I have immediately noticed it lacking is scrolling via the mouse scroll wheel through icons stored in the sidebar. This was my primary way of getting up and down the sidebar through icons I've stored there, and now it no longer works. Great. Is this something that can be fixed or what? If so then how?

Answer (score 0):

The less than ideal solution to this is to suck it up, and move your mouse cursor to the top/bottom of the launcher to scroll instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable sidebar scrolling by using dconf-editor.

[Enable sidebar scrolling in Ubuntu 13.04](http://www.ubuntucafe.in/2013/05/how-to-enable-sidebar-and-natural.html)